# Django Frontend Inline Form with related models

Tags: django-forms, django-views

I'm a python/django newbie. Sorry for my english I'm not a native english speaker. I am trying to make a form where users can add in related models. On the admin site I am able to do this however I am having a hard time implementing the same thing on the website end.

Below is the admin screenshot. I want to implement on the front end the same thing where there's a way to add New Artist and New Tags to the form.

http://postimg.org/image/lv83s9fq5/

Here's my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from uuslug import uuslug
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug


class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Song(models.Model):
    S_KEYS = (
        ('C', 'C'),
        ('C#', 'C#'),
        ('D', 'D'),
        ('D#', 'D#'),
        ('E', 'E'),
        ('F', 'F'),
        ('F#', 'F#'),
        ('G', 'G'),
        ('G#', 'G#'),
        ('A', 'A'),
        ('A#', 'A#'),
        ('B', 'B'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    song_key = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=S_KEYS)
    body = models.TextField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["title"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = uuslug(self.title, instance=self, max_length=100)
        super(Song, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def add_view_count(self):
        if self.views is not None:
            self.views +=1
```

Here's what's in my views.py

```
class SongAdd(generic.CreateView):
    template_name= 'song/add.html'
    model = Song
    form_class = SongForm
    success_url = '/'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(SongAdd, self).form_valid(form)
```

I hope you can help me :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use [django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) app, the same that admin use with the name inlines.js. It has good examples for exactly what you need.